# How to extract a property value of a child node in a styled component and pass it as props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using multiple instances of the **'Icons'** component. I was trying to access and **use width** of the **'a' tag** inside the **'Icons' styled component**(Here 'a' tag is inside 'Icons' component). Since the content of 'a' tag changes its width also changes. That is why I want to use the **width of the 'a' tag** inside each 'Icons' component.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import home from "../images/home-icon.svg";
import search from "../images/search-icon.svg";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar>
      <Icons imgUrl={home}>
        <div className="special-underline"></div>
        <a className="text-container" href="/">HOME</a>
      </Icons>
      <Icons imgUrl={search}>
        <div className="special-underline"></div>
        <a className="text-container" href="/">SEARCH</a>
      </Icons>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
const Icons=styled.div`
//css styling 
//here I want to access and use width of the anchor component of that Icons component
`
```

I tried using useRef hook and referencing the 'a' tag but it didn't work. I just could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style Icons width dynamically adding `width: fit-content`.

I wrote a similar example to your code, replacing Icons component with a div with class `Icons`, but the general idea applies to styled components.

*Edit: the width of the div with class `special-underline` will also adjust accordingly and be the same as of the a tag. I edited the snippet below to show this.

```css
.Icons {
  width: fit-content; /* <- Here */
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.special-underline {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Icons">
  <div class="special-underline"></div>
  <a>HOME</a>
</div>

<div class="Icons">
<div class="special-underline"></div>
  <a>SEARCH</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I want a numerical value somehow because I want to set width of ".special-underline" div equals to the width of the "a" tag.

Comment: Got it. You can still style that dynamically, I edited my answer to clarify that. As for how to access a child element's width from a styled component, unfortunately I don't know of a way to do that and so I can't help you.

Comment: Yes you are right "width: fit-content" worked. Thanks for help.